# Email Spoofing Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I'm getting returned email in my indox that I nerver sent before,How Can I use Cpanel to stop it, my inbox alway filled up.
I read this article
http://www.werockyourweb.com/stop-spoof-email
But it seen doesn't work for me. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

It seem some email system block my email address, it look like
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent has not yet been delivered to one or more of its
recipients after more than 24 hours on the queue

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know a sample header of the similar mail from queue

Make sure that the domain engaged in the process is having a valid SPF(TXT) record.

[SPF](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Spoofing can be done in many ways like if you have any form which may have bug in it and causing spamming from it .. or many any of your signup process form has bug which allows spamming over it

if its clear spoofing then yes SPF and DKIM will help to reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct! Adding DKIM and SPF should help to reduce the spoof emails. If you will paste the headers here, we can identify the real cause of it. You will find it from the returned email as well from the server logs.